# How to play .swf through HTML code

Tags: html, flash

I have a swf named "client.swf" on my desktop, and I want to add it to my website so people can play the .swf on there, but the website only accepts HTML content, and not .swf, whats an html code I can use for it to load the .swf from my desktop? or another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `<object> </object>` tag and also use the `<iframe></iframe>`

```
 <iframe src="client.swf" width="200" heigt="200"></iframe>


    <object width="500" height="500">
        <param name="media" value="client.swf">
        <embed src="client.swf" width="500" height="500">
        </embed>
    </object>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the iframe and that works fine, you spelt height wrong though btw, might wanna fix that for the future when others stumble upon this page and copy and paste that.

Comment: ya its height sorry for that miss spelling

Answer (score 1):

SWF into a HTML page is to use  [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

Just example

```
<object width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="my.swf">
    <embed src="my.swf" width="100" height="100">
    </embed>
</object>
```